# Check if image exist in Parse.com

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

How can i check if a image exist in parse?

This is my query code:

```
func queryFromParse(){
        self.imageFiles.removeAll()
        var query = PFQuery(className: "currentUploads")
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (posts: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                // Success fetching objects
                for post in posts!{
                    println(post)
                    self.imageFiles.append(post["imageFile"] as! PFFile)
                    self.imageText.append(post["imageText"] as! String)
                }
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                println(self.imageFiles.count)

            }
            else{
                println(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

If a image fails to upload to parse, it looks like this:
[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8AKl.png)

The application crashes if the does not contains a image, so how can i check if the image exist and skip it, if it does not include a image?

Comment: you can use query.whereKeyExists("keyName") by using PFQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is crashing because you're using a force casting in the block (post["imageFile"] as! PFFile and post["imageText"] as! String). But there is also another problem in your code. self.collectionView.reloadData() is a ui code so it needs to be done on the main queue. The findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock method runs the block in a different thread so the closure might be executed some time later after the function has already returned. You use dispatch_async to get the main queue if you have a UI related stuff to be done in the closure.

```
if let unwrappedPosts = posts as? [PFObject] {
     for post in unwrappedPosts{
         println(post)
         if let file = post["imageFile"] as? PFFile {self.imageFiles.append(file) }
         if let text = post["imageText"] as? String { self.imageText.append(text) } //the above to if lets are to be extremely safe (probably not necessary)
     }
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
         self.collectionView.reloadData()
         print(self.imageFiles.count)        
     })
} else { print("found nil") }
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! Can you please take a quick look at this: http://pastebin.com/BwsZjwU6 - I am trying to make the "cell.imageTimeLabel.text" says like "1 minute ago", "5 minutes ago" and so on.. But when i run the application, it crashes.. What can be wrong?

Comment: Thats a lot of code, it takes time to go through your project so I'd use breakpoints to figure out where it crashes and post that code here

Comment: In my ´cellForItemAtIndexPath´ it crashes here: ´cell.imageTimeLabel.text = self.imageCreated[indexPath.row]´ - Any ideas?

Comment: is imageCreated[indexPath.row] a string?

Comment: Uhm, it´s a date(?): http://s21.postimg.org/lndwq6w07/Screen_Shot_2015_10_18_at_23_49_28.png - and also: `var imageCreated = [String]()`

Comment: imageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock. This block will be handled in a different thread so you can not do any ui stuff here. All ui related things run on the main thread so every time you wanna update your ui in a closure that runs on a different thread such as this, dispatch to the main queue and do the updates there.

Comment: you can do the "let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)" before you dispatch but that'll work too

Comment: It just crashes: http://s10.postimg.org/p6omwhcll/Screen_Shot_2015_10_19_at_00_22_07.png

Comment: Trying and trying.. Can´t figure out anything.. If i remove the line `cell.imageTimeLabel.text = self.imageCreated[indexPath.row]`it works fine without any error/crash.. Not sure what to do.. EDIT: When i do `println(self.imageCreated)` it return nothing. It is blank(?)

Comment: That means the array is empty so when you try to access data in [indexPath.row] it crashes telling you array out of bounce or something similar. try this line 

if indexPath.row <= self.imageCreated.count { cell.imageTimeLabel.text = self.imageCreated[indexPath.row] }